# ESP8266 SDK 1.5.2 Smart Config 2.5.3 with ESP-Touch Android app

Tags: android, esp8266

I'm using the [ESP8266 SDK 1.5.2](http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=1702) and trying to get smart config working with an android app. With smart config I can transmit the SSID and password for the access point which that the ESP8266 should connect.

I'm using the example code from the [SDK 1.5.2 documentation page 108/109](http://bbs.espressif.com/download/file.php?id=1106).

```
void ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR smartconfig_done(sc_status status, void *pdata)
{
    switch (status) {
    case SC_STATUS_WAIT:
        os_printf("SC_STATUS_WAIT\n");
        break;
    case SC_STATUS_FIND_CHANNEL:
        os_printf("SC_STATUS_FIND_CHANNEL\n");
        break;
    case SC_STATUS_GETTING_SSID_PSWD:
        os_printf("SC_STATUS_GETTING_SSID_PSWD\n");
        sc_type *type = pdata;
        if (*type == SC_TYPE_ESPTOUCH) {
            os_printf("SC_TYPE:SC_TYPE_ESPTOUCH\n");
        }
        else {
            os_printf("SC_TYPE:SC_TYPE_AIRKISS\n");
        }
        break;
    case SC_STATUS_LINK:
        os_printf("SC_STATUS_LINK\n");
        struct station_config *sta_conf = pdata;
        wifi_station_set_config(sta_conf);
        wifi_station_disconnect();
        wifi_station_connect();
        break;
    case SC_STATUS_LINK_OVER:
        os_printf("SC_STATUS_LINK_OVER\n");
        if (pdata != NULL) {
            uint8 phone_ip[4] = { 0 };
            memcpy(phone_ip, (uint8*)pdata, 4);
            os_printf("Phone ip: %d.%d.%d.%d\n",phone_ip[0],phone_ip[1],phone_ip[2],phone_ip[3]);
        }
        smartconfig_stop();
        break;
    }
}
```

Before I call

```
smartconfig_start(smartconfig_done);
```

I disconnect from station and set the ESP8266 to station mode:

```
wifi_station_disconnect();
wifi_set_opmode_current(STATION_MODE);
```

When smart config is started my callback will be called with status SC_STATUS_FIND_CHANNEL. Then I try to connect via the following androig apps:

[ESP Smart Config](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qwavesys.smartconfig&hl=de)

[ESP8266 SmartConfig](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cmmakerclub.iot.esptouch&hl=de)

[IOT_Espressif](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.espressif.iot&hl=de)

With ESP Smart Config and ESP8266 SmartConfig nothing will happen. My smartconfig_done callback will never called again.

With IOT_Espressif I get called with status SC_STATUS_GETTING_SSID_PSWD and the log tells me that the ESP-Touch protocol is used and which phone MAC and which access point MAC will be used. But then I will not be called with status SC_STATUS_LINK and SC_STATUS_LINK_OVER.

Has anyboby got SmartConfig 2.5.3 which is used in SDK 1.5.2 working with an android app?

Or is the ESP-Touch protocol that should be used for SmartConfig 2.5.3 somewhere described?

The source code for IOT_Espressif can be found [here](https://github.com/EspressifApp/IOT-Espressif-Android). And the source code for a demo ESP-Touch android app is found [here](https://github.com/EspressifApp/EsptouchForAndroid). In the demo app it's written that it will only work with SmartConfig 2.4.

Maybe something has changed between SmartConfig 2.4 and 2.5.3. But what is changed?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: No. I didn't get this solved.

Comment: same issue SmartConfig 2.5.4 and EspTouch 0.3.7.0